# Suddenly unable to connect to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, connections

I have a simple backend running on a server back at my house while I'm away at college. I had it just sitting there, doing nothing, with daily endpoint tests for about a month, when suddenly yesterday the endpoint tests failed.

I SSHd to the server, and saw that the error given was

```
FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "username"
```

at the line where `pg` tries to connect to the postgres database, line 24 [here](https://github.com/JacksonKearl/LilyPad/blob/master/LilyPadBackend/routes/authentication.js).

The `connectionString` hasn't been changed, neither has `pg_hba.conf`. What could cause the error?

In the log, I get

```
{ [error: Ident authentication failed for user "jkearl"]
 name: 'error',
 length: 92,
 severity: 'FATAL',
 code: '28000',
 detail: undefined,
 hint: undefined,
 position: undefined,
 internalPosition: undefined,
 internalQuery: undefined,
 where: undefined,
 schema: undefined,
 table: undefined,
 column: undefined,
 dataType: undefined,
 constraint: undefined,
 file: 'auth.c',
 line: '304',
 routine: 'auth_failed' }

/home/jkearl/LilyPad/LilyPadBackend/routes/authentication.js:25
   var query = client.query(cleanser('SELECT * FROM lilypad.people '+
                   ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'query' of null
```

And in postgres's log:

```
2015-10-19 22:04:15 PDT LOG:  could not connect to Ident server at address  "127.0.0.1", port 113: Connection refused
2015-10-19 22:04:15 PDT FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "jkearl"
2015-10-19 22:04:15 PDT DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 92: "host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident"
```

Comment: Look for an error message in the server log, not the client log.  The message sent to the client is intentionally uninformative, to avoid leaking security-sensitive data to an attacker.

Comment: That was in server log. In the linked code, `client` is reported as undefined, and `err` is an object containing the aforementioned description, among other things.

Comment: When I break my ident service, I get 3 lines in the server log.  Before the FATAL is `LOG:  could not connect to Ident server at address "127.0.0.1", port 113: Connection refused` and after is `DETAIL:  Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 87: "host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident"`

Comment: edited to show log

Comment: So, does the OS user (`jkearl`) on the client side have its counterpart in the database?

Comment: I'd assume so. I remember creating a user, and like I said, it was working fine until just a few days ago.

Comment: @Jackson as magic does not exist, there must be something different now from a few days ago.  You should absolutely check **everything** that may affect the connection - user existence, password, etc.

Comment: @jjanes I got the same log. How does one break an Ident service, and how would one go about fixing it?

Comment: I've just removed/reinstalled. Works now. Hope this don't happen with lave data. Oh well.

Comment: I used `sudo service xinetd stop` to break it.  I have no idea how to fix it (other than restarting the daemon).  You might have better luck on the unix site